# How to build a triger in MySQL that update a table when adding or deleting?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table's
Queue (appointment_id, actual_time)
Queue_Summary (date, doctor_id, num_of_patients)

The first is all the queues there are and the second is how many queues for each doctor on a certain date.
I need to build a trigger that updates the num_of_patients, every time in Queue that a queue is added I need to add to a doctor num_of_patients in that date. Also when removing.

I have just counted the number of queues given a doctor_id and date.

```
delimiter //
 CREATE TRIGGER update_queue_summary 
    BEFORE UPDATE ON queue
    FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
            update queue_summary as qs set num_of_patient = ( 
                select count(appointment_id) 
                from queue as q join appointment as a on appointment_id
                where a.doctor_id=qs.doctor_id and date(qs.actual_time)=date(qs.date())
                group by appointment_id
                ) where doctor_id=qs.doctor_id and date(qs.actual_time)=date(qs.date());
       END;//
 delimiter ;
```

But it's not working well!
Can someone point where is the mistake?

Comment: You seem to want an insert an a delete trigger (you cannot combine insert/delete) and I don't get why you have an update trigger at all.

Comment: Well, this is the problem I have at hand I need to do a single trigger that updates the num_of_patients when adding/deleting a queue.
As I'm new to SQL I have tried to go with the logic of update.
is there no way to know when the queue is "edited" in the same trigger ?

Answer (score 2):

A trigger is expected to refer to `NEW` and/or `OLD`, so that is an issue.  I think the logic you want is:

```
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER update_queue_summary 
BEFORE UPDATE ON queue
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        update queue_summary
            set num_of_patient = num_of_patient + 1
            where doctor_id = new.doctor_id and date = date(new.actual_time);
        update queue_summary
            set num_of_patient = num_of_patient - 1
            where doctor_id = old.doctor_id and date = date(old.actual_time);
   END;//

 delimiter ;
```

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance but how will the trigger know when a queue is added and when it's deleted?
Could you please explain the code a bit more

Comment: @EladAskenazi . . . It doesn't.  This is an `update` trigger.  If you want a `delete` trigger, then that would be a separate trigger.

Comment: So there is no way to make a trigger that know when I add or delete from the queue at the same time?
Also, I still don't understand your code and why it does two updates?

Comment: @EladAskenazi . . . There is, but not in MySQL.  Other databases do support combining multiple actions into one trigger.

Comment: Could you help me out in guiding me on how to split it properly into two triggers? @GordonLinoff